# Utilização de laço de repetição de forma adequada

Tags: java, loop

> "Uma brincadeira muito comum entre 3 amigos é o jogo do 2 ou 1. Neste jogo, o vencedor é aquele diferente dos outros dois e, caso os três escolham valores iguais, o jogo termina empatado. Assim, considere três amigos A, B e C, que estão jogando 2 ou 1: seu programa deve mostrar qual deles é o vencedor ou se houve empate. Para isto leia um número N que indica o total de partidas que eles irão jogar e, após isto, leia os valores A, B e C (inteiros) de cada amigo. Considere que estes valores sempre serão 2 ou 1. Mostre na tela quem foi o ganhador ou se houve empate. O programa encerrará quando N for zero.

Meu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero1 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    int numero2 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    int numero3 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    int N;
    System.out.println("DOIS OU UM!");
    System.out.print("Quantas partidas serão jogadas? ");
    do {
        N = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Jogador 1: "+numero1);
        System.out.println("Jogador 2: "+numero2);
        System.out.println("Jogador 3: "+numero3);
        System.out.println("------------");
        if (numero1 != numero2 && numero1 != numero3)
            System.out.println("Jogador 1 venceu!");
        else if (numero2 != numero1 && numero2 != numero3)
            System.out.println("Jogador 2 venceu!");
        else if (numero3 != numero1 && numero3 != numero2)
            System.out.println("Jogador 3 venceu!");
        else
            System.out.println("O jogo terminou empatado!");
        break;

    } while (N > 0);

    System.out.println("Fim de Jogo!");

}
```

O código até que está validando quem é o vencedor e se deu empate. O problema está na quantidade que informo, e ele mostra apenas uma vez, e quando insiro 0 ele não vai direto para o "Fim de Jogo!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você ler com atenção o enunciado verá que o código não faz o mesmo que está escrito lá.

Um dos erros é que pede quantas partidas vai jogar todas as vezes que faz uma partida.

Outro erro é que não está decrementando o número de jogadas faltantes.

Um `break` logo antes do fim do laço é o mesmo que nada.

Mesmo que fosse para pedir ainda se quer jogar teria que instruir o computador para sair imediatamente, ele não sai magicamente porque alguém digitou algum número. O computador precisa ser instruído em cada detalhe.

Assim funciona e fica mais legível:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero1 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    int numero2 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    int numero3 = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    System.out.println("DOIS OU UM!");
    System.out.print("Quantas partidas serão jogadas? ");
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numPartidas = ler.nextInt();
    do {
        System.out.println("Jogador 1: " + numero1);
        System.out.println("Jogador 2: " + numero2);
        System.out.println("Jogador 3: " + numero3);
        System.out.println("------------");
        if (numero1 != numero2 && numero1 != numero3) System.out.println("Jogador 1 venceu!");
        else if (numero2 != numero1 && numero2 != numero3) System.out.println("Jogador 2 venceu!");
        else if (numero3 != numero1 && numero3 != numero2) System.out.println("Jogador 3 venceu!");
        else System.out.println("O jogo terminou empatado!");
    } while (--numPartidas > 0);
    System.out.println("Fim de Jogo!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cvXYA7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kxxptemp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Plays.java).

As outras variáveis ainda poderiam ter nomes melhores.

Estou confiando que a lógica geral esteja correta.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo! Eu estava mesmo quebrando a cabeça com o do...while e foi o detalhe do decremento. Agradeço também a explicação do break dentro do laço. Boa noite!